# Is it optimal to force SSL on my site at CDN, Web Server or Code level?

Tags: tomcat, ssl, redirect, cdn

We are implementing a redirect rule to force our traffic to SSL.  I was wondering what the most optimal way to force all traffic to SSL was?  Our architecture has a CDN(Akamai), that is front of an ELB, that is in front of our web application server(tomcat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://serverfault.com/a/887312/92022:

> Do it in Akamai. The closer to the edge your redirect takes place, the
>   faster the request response time will be for your users.
>
> https://blogs.akamai.com/2016/02/redirecting-on-the-edge.html
>
> If you're confident that you can serve your entire domain over HTTPS
>   now and into the future then you should also look into enabling HSTS.
>   This will mean only first time visitors ever get the HTTP->HTTPS
>   redirect, then the HSTS header gets cached in the browser and
>   thereafter all requests are automatically upgraded to HTTPS by the
>   browser before the request is initiated.
>
> https://blogs.akamai.com/2016/04/ensure-secure-browsing-with-HTTP-strict-transport-security-HSTS.html
>
> https://jackiechen.org/2017/11/13/enable-hsts-in-akamai/